# GraphicsGrid resizes plot when using SpanFromLeft

Tags: plotting, graphics

When I run the following code

```
grx = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> {200, 200}];
GraphicsGrid[{{grx, grx}, {grx, SpanFromLeft}}, Frame -> {True, True}]
```

I get the following

[image]

Why is the bottom figure not the same size as the others?

Comment: use `Grid ` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
grx = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> {200, 200}];
```

You can use `Grid`:

```
Grid[{{grx, grx}, {grx, SpanFromLeft}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Alternatively, wrap the first entry in the second row with `Pane`:

```
GraphicsGrid[{{grx, grx}, {Pane[grx, ImageSize -> {200, 200}],  SpanFromLeft}}, 
  Frame -> {True, True}]
```

[image]

And, this may be of interest:

```
GraphicsGrid[{{grx, grx}, {Item @ grx, SpanFromLeft}}, Frame -> {True, True}]
```

[image]

Comment: @locx this feels a like a work-around a bug. is it?

btw, nice work. i gave it an up arrow checkmark.

Comment: @JulesManson It is. How can problems like this exist in something that's been around so long? And is expensive.